# Using tabular(*?) with two languages

Tags: tables, hebrew

I wish to have an invisible table (using the `tabular` or `tabular*` environments) which should contain two columns - one shall contain sentences in English, and the other - their translations in Hebrew.

For that I want the left column to be aligned such it begins at the beginning of the row for English speakers (i.e. left), and the right column - at the beginning of the row for Hebrew speakers (i.e. all the way to the right). How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking about the placement of the columns relative to the page, or the alignment of the text within each column?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for something that is provided by packages like [paracol](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol), [parallel](http://ctan.org/pkg/parallel) or [parcolumns](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I could tell, they all provide environment for translating two left-to-right languages, so the alignment isn't as I wanted. Am I missing something?

Comment: All suggested packages provide environments for the alignment you asked for. Just give them a try and test if you can do with them what you want.